# How add multiple same jar files into another project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar

I am working on a project,

where I have Project A and in that project A have lots of jar file and that all jar file depends another project B.
How to add project A jar file into Project B.

Comment: The JAR files are only visible to depending projects if and only if they will be exported (which is not the case by default): _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ in tab _Order and Export_ check the JARs that you want to use also in the projects that depend on this project.

Comment: Hi Howlger, I trying to do this things likes  projectA jars files export and adding into projectB, But it not adding into projectB.

Comment: When projectB depends on projectA (in the _Java Build Path_ of projectB in tab _Projects_ projectA has been added), projectA has to contain and export the JAR files. This works for me. If it does not work for you, please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I want all the Referenced Libraries of projectA into projectB as a Referenced Libraries

Comment: When projectB depends on projectA, the JARs has to be added and exported in projectA to have them in both projects as _Referenced Libraries_.

Comment: yes I got the solution thanks howlger for your help.